# My script doesnt work,how do i make it work?

Tags: roblox

Im making a story roblox game and everything has worked out so far exept for this script:

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
if hit:FindFirstAncestor("Picnic") then
    game.ServerScriptService.Main.BasketReturned:Fire()
end
```

end)

But the thing that doesnt work is
the:`'game.ServerScriptService.Main.BasketReturned:Fire()'`

and when i run the game it says: 'Main is not a valid member of ServerScriptService "ServerScriptService" ' Any ideas on how i fix it?

Comment: Do you have anything in ServerScriptService named `Main`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Oh thank you! I forgot that part hehe,But thank you i hope this fixes my problem!